# How to call a members function in a Truffle test?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Consider the following setting:

```
contract A {
    B public b = new B();
}

contract B {
    function C() public pure returns (uint c)
    {
        c = 5;
    }
}
```

From a Truffle test, having an instance of A, how to call function C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to call C in a Truffle test:

```
const A = artifacts.require('A')
const B = artifacts.require('B')

contract('A', function(accounts) {
    it('should be possible to call C', async function() {
        let a = await A.new({from: accounts[0]})
        let addressOfB = await a.b();
        let contractB = web3.eth.contract(B.abi)
        let b = contractB.at(addressOfB)
        console.log("Output of C: " + await (b.C()).toNumber());
    })
})
```

> Contract: A
>
> Output of C: 5
>
> ✓ should be possible to call C (380ms)
>
> 1 passing (400ms)